# Comparison of Linear dependency between $2$ families of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n$ be a linear transformation, where $n\geq 2$. For $k\leq n$, 
let $E=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k\}$ contained in, equal to $R^n$ and $F=\{Tv_1,Tv_2,\dots,Tv_k\}$.
Then

a). If $E$ is linearly independent, then $F$ is linearly independent.

b). If $F$ is linearly independent, then $E$ is linearly independent.

c). If $E$ is linearly independent, then $F$ is linearly dependent.

d). If $F$ is linearly independent, then $E$ is linearly dependent.

a) part can be correct if $T$ is one-one. And since our transformation is finite dimensional $n$-to-$n$. Therefore, it is one-one, which implies that $F$ is linearly independent if $E$ is linearly independent.

I thought of part c) as follows: supposingly I take $E=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ contained in $\Bbb R^3$ and $F=\{T(1,0,0),T(0,1,0)\}$. Now $E$ is linearly independent, if I define $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=((x_1+x_2),0,x_3)$ then $T(1,0,0)=(1,0,0)$ and $T(0,1,0)=(1,0,0)$ , this shows that $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ are linearly dependent.

This implies that both part a) and c) are correct? can someone please give the explaination for part b) and d)?

Comment: I don't get it. Are $a,b,c,d$ options out of which more than one can be correct?

Comment: I think the question is which of the options a), b), c), d) are correct.

Comment: Are you sure (c) and (d) weren't meant to be "dependent => dependent" statements?

Comment: I've edited the title because it contained a few errors : first, the question is not about $E$ or $F$ being a basis, and second, if they were bases it would be of $\Bbb R^n$, not of $T$.

Comment: @StackTD yes the quest is correct in its form.

Comment: @ArnaudD. the duplicate do not sought my queries out

Comment: yes, one or more are correct @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right when you say that a) is true if $T$ is one-to-one. However, you seem to assume that because $T$ is a transformation between two spaces of the same dimension it has to be one-to-one. This is **not** true, and you even give a counter-example yourself in your next paragraph!

Option b) is always true. To see this, suppose that $F$ is linearly independent and that
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\cdot v_i=0$$
for some $a_1,\dots,a_k\in \Bbb R$. It follows immediately that
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\cdot Tv_i=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\cdot v_i\right)=T(0)=0;$$
since $F$ is linearly independent, $a_i=0$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$. Hence $E$ is linearly independent.

For option c) you are making a logical mistake : you have given one example where the implication holds, but this does not mean it has to be true for all possible choice of $T$, $E$ and $F$. It is in fact not the case; for example, with your same choice of $T$, take $E=\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\}$. $E$ is linearly independent; but so is
$$F=\{T(1,0,0),T(0,0,1)\}=\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\}!$$

As for option d), it is certainly false, because b) is true.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 and 4 is correct.
 $T:R^2\to R^2$ defined by $T(x,y)=(x+y,x+y)$. Clearly T is L.I.\
 Now
$T(1,0)=(1,1),\ T(0,1)=(1,1). \ E=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ are L.I but $T(E)$ are L.D. So option 3 is correct.
Suppose $F=\{T(v_1),T(v_2),.....T(v_k)\}$ are L.I
Consider
$$
\alpha_1 v_1+....\alpha_k v_k=0.\\
\implies T(\alpha_1v_1+....\alpha_kv_k)=T(0)=0.\\
\implies\alpha_1 T(v_1)+..........\alpha_kT(v_k)=0
$$
Since F is L.I so E is L.

option 2 is correct

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: a) can be true or false depending on $T$ and $k\le n$. When $T$ is one-one, it is always true but if $T$ is not one-one and $E$ is linearly independent and $k\lt n$ both cases can happen, $F$ be linearly independent and linearly dependent (why?).

$b)$ is always true.

$c)$ is true only when $T$ is not one-one.

$d)$ never happens because $T(\sum a_iv_i)=\sum a_iT(v_i)$